# Access Query to multiply

Tags: ms-access

```
Year Month  Exchange rate  
2014           54                                             
2015           60  

Year  Amount
2014  5000
2015  6000
```

I want to multiply amount in every year to exchange rate corresponding to that year.

SELECT Currency.[Year Month], Currency.[Echange Rate], Loss.[Year], Loss.[Amount] AS NewAmount=Currency.[Echange Rate]*Loss.[Amount] FROM [Currency],[Loss]

Thank you for your help

Comment: When asking questions about database queries the names of the tables are critical.

Comment: Please provide an example of what did you try yourself

Comment: Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question to include what you tried.

Answer (score 0):

NewAmount is the calculated field.  The AS part comes after the multiplication, and there is no =.
Use the related fields, the primary key and foreign key, for the ??RELATED_FIELD?? parts.  [Year] and [Month] should really be separate fields.

SELECT
    [Currency].[Year Month],
    [Currency].[Exchange Rate],
    [Loss].[Year],
    [Loss].[Amount],
    [Currency].[Exchange Rate]*[Loss].[Amount] AS NewAmount
FROM [Currency] LEFT OUTER JOIN [Loss]
ON [Currency].[??RELATED_FIELD??] = [Loss].[??RELATED_FIELD??]